# Linearization attacks

Tags: c, security

I understand what a linearization attack is and how it is performed. I just wanted some clarity on how the code below allows for it since it should terminate with the same iteration count if the string entered is equal or greater than 8?

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

int i;
boolean flag = true;
char serial [9] = “S123N456\n”;
if(strlen(argv[1]) < 8)
{
printf(“\nError try again.\n\n”);
exit(0);

}

for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{

    if(argv[1][i] != serial[i])flag = false;

}

if(flag)
{

    printf(“\bSerial number is correct!\n\n”);

}

}
```

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_attack)? That doesn't look related to the code in the question.

Comment: The definition of a linearization attack would help immensely.

Answer (score 1):

A linear attack is an attack that takes advantage certain coding flaws. If the above code ended when a incorrect character was entered an attacker could use that to determine how many correct characters were entered. I worked through it with a tutor and now I see that since the flag is set every time it is incorrect if 5 of 7 are incorrect and the flag it set 5 times. That attempt will run faster than if it was set all 7 times. So if an attacker tries every possible solution for the first character and inserts a standard character for the remaining portion of the string. The attempt with the correct first character will run slightly faster. Apply the same logic to each character will eventually obtain the serial number.

Comment: That's how the book "Information security principles and practice" by Mark stamp referred to it as. I'll read up on timing attacks though to see how they compare.